# Can I search for text shown in Terminal by color?

Tags: terminal

If I run commands in Terminal the output is sometimes shown in red or green depending on the command.

[image]

How do I search for such text by color (e.g. "Anything red" to find the line starting with "Connection refused")?

Comment: Can you pipe that command into a cat -v to see how that particular program is calling on the red text. `mycmd | cat -v`